# Wrong labels in the inception v3 network (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, computer-vision, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am using build_image_data.py script from here:https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/data/build_image_data.py 
exactly like the documentation to convert my dataset to TFRecords format. In the inception_train.py script, when I print images and labels, labels do not correspond to the images so I can't proceed to right training. The dataset I am using is unbalanced (different number of images between classes). I also made a test using the same number of images between classes and labels are still wrong. The tensorflow code is untouched, the only change I made is not applying distortions in the image_processing.py script. I don't know if labels are wrong because of my TFR conversion or because of image_processing.py script which returns images and labels. Any ideas?

Tensorflow version: 0.10 
OS: Ubuntu 14.04

The snippet of code in the inception_train.py script to check it is:

```
labs = sess.run(labels)
imgs = sess.run(images)


for i in range(FLAGS.batch_size):
  print('Label ' + str(labs[i]))
  plt.imshow(imgs[i, :, :, :])
  plt.show()
```

Comment: You mentioned making a change - does it work if you use completely fresh scripts?

Comment: No it's not working with distortions applied too.

Comment: I made a lot of prints in the build_image_data.py script and labels were right so possibly there is a mistake in image_processing.py script. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run both at the same time: that is, only make one call to sess.run. Something like this:

```
imgs,labs = sess.run([images,labels])# ONLY ONE CALL 

for i in range(FLAGS.batch_size):
    print('Label ' + str(labs[i]))
    plt.imshow(imgs[i, :, :, :])
    plt.show()
```